# matplotlib set ylim in axis units

Tags: python, matplotlib

In matplotlib is there a way to set the ylim of a chart in axes units?

I am plotting a dataset that goes from 0 to 100 (this upper bound can change depending on the dataset). I am trying to create a "buffer" underneath this plot with some other lines. To do this I am setting the ylim so that instead of going from 0 to 100, it goes from -20 to 100 and now I have 20 data units at the bottom to use as padding.

In matplotlib is there a way to say y = 0 should be at 0.1 on the axes scale?

Comment: you can change `plt.margins(y=0.2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just calculate the scale factor and set the lower limit by subtracting 20 units of scale from the minimum value like so:

```
y = np.ndarray()   # Some data to be plotted on y-axis
scale = (np.maximum(y) - np.minimum(y)) / 100

### later in the code when you're setting y_lim
y_min = np.minimum(y) - 20 * scale
y_max = np.maximum(y)

ax.set_ylim(y_min, y_max)   # Now set the limits of y-axis
```